# Special char in password for smb mount

Tags: password, samba, samba4

These are lines containing smb mounts in my /etc/fstab

```
//192.168.2.2/Company /home/myname/server/company cifs users,credentials=/home/myname/.smbcredentials,uid=1000,gid=1000,noauto 0 0
//192.168.2.2/Private /home/myname/server/private cifs users,credentials=/home/myname/.smbcredentials,uid=1000,gid=1000,noauto 0 0
```

The .smbcredentials-File contains a passwort with special chars, for example like:

```
username=myname
password=%t!f?ea-TGH
```

The mount doesn't work, because of the special chars. Is there a way to escape the chars? I tried to enframe it with `"` or `'`- but it doesn't work.

Comment: Does the password really have a leading space? The BUGS section of the `mount.cifs` man page suggests that is unsupported (*"The credentials file does not handle usernames or passwords with leading space."*)

Comment: Oh, sorry, my mistake, this was only an example. I wouldn't post a real password online.

Answer (score 1):

```
password= %t\!f\?ea-TGH
```

The escape character is `\`, this should work.